# Oracle - Select with math and groupings

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that I'd like to run some calculations on but this select statement is above my oracle wheelhouse.

I wanted to attempt (as much of this) in oracle. But ultimately this will end up getting run through php to get output to the screen.

**This is for Oracle 8i**

**I have 4 important pieces of data** - (Customer Id, New_Item, Suggested_net, and Volume by year)

```
customer_id = #
new_item = 0 or 1
suggested_net = #
year_1_n =  #
year_2_n =  #
year_3_n =  #
year_1_e =  #
year_2_e =  #
year_3_e =  #
```

new_items = 0 correlates only to year_1_e, year_2_e, year_3_e

new_items = 1 correlates only to year_1_n, year_2_n, year_3_n

**Here's an example**

```
customer_id, new_item, suggested_net, year_1_n, year_2_n, year_3_n, year_1_e, year_2_e, year_3_e

2, 0, 4.25, null, null, null, 100, 100, 100;
2, 0, 5.25, null, null, null, 100, 100, 100;
3, 0, 2.50, null, null, null, 100, 100, 100;
1, 0, 3.50, null, null, null, 100, 100, 100;
2, 1, 5.99, 100, 200, 300, null, null, null;
3, 1, 4.99, 200, 400, 600, null, null, null;
```

**So I need to get this info:**
For each row, add the volumes up (year_x...) * suggested_net, Then add that amount to a grouped customer_id by new_item = 0 or 1.

So using the above table

```
Customer 2, new_item = 0 would have a sum of (1275 + 1575)
Customer 1, new_item = 0 would have a sum of 1050
Customer 2, new_item = 1 would have a sum of 3594
```

etc. etc.

Now this may or may not be possible or efficient to do in a select statement, but like I said I wanted to do as much of the heavy lifting with oracle, the rest I can handle with php.

Comment: This can be easily implemented by using Group clause in Select query. But what exactly you want?

Comment: I need the info outlined in the last 'code' block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Coustomer_Id,
       new_item,
       SUM((CASE WHEN new_item = 1 THEN year_1_n + year_2_n + year_3_n 
                 WHEN new_item = 0 THEN year_1_e + year_2_e + year_3_e
            END ) * suggested_net) AS TotalSum
  FROM Table1
 GROUP BY Coustomer_Id,
       new_item
```

OR

```
SELECT Coustomer_Id,
       new_item,
       SUM(DECODE(new_item, 1, year_1_n + year_2_n + year_3_n 
                          , 0, year_1_e + year_2_e + year_3_e
                          , 0) * suggested_net) AS TotalSum
  FROM Table1
 GROUP BY Coustomer_Id,
          new_item
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select customer_id
     , new_item
     , sum((nvl(year_1_n, 0) + 
            nvl(year_2_n, 0) + 
            nvl(year_3_n, 0) +
            nvl(year_1_e, 0) + 
            nvl(year_2_e, 0) + 
            nvl(year_3_e, 0)) *suggested_net) Total
  from t1
 group by customer_id
        , new_item
```

Comment: clever to add all of the year_x_x. I wouldn't have thought to do that.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

select
  customer_id
, new_item
, sum(case new_item when 0 then suggested_net*(year_1_e+year_2_e+year_3_e)
                           else suggested_net*(year_1_n+year_2_n+year_3_n) end) total

from table

group by customer_id, new_item;